How can I find my sagemaker endpoint in? (don't know region)
I was following this tutorial:
https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/main/introduction_to_amazon_algorithms/jumpstart-foundation-models/llama-2-chat-completion.ipynb
And created a Llama 2 model with
from sagemaker.jumpstart.model import JumpStartModel

model = JumpStartModel(model_id=model_id, model_version=model_version)
predictor = model.deploy()

However, I didn't delete the model, nor the endpoint and now when I try running again I get this error:
botocore.errorfactory.ResourceLimitExceeded: An error occurred (ResourceLimitExceeded) when calling the CreateEndpoint operation: The account-level service limit 'ml.g5.2xlarge for endpoint usage' is 2 Instances, with current utilization of 2 Instances and a request delta of 1 Instances. Please use AWS Service Quotas to request an increase for this quota. If AWS Service Quotas is not available, contact AWS support to request an increase for this quota.

I'd be perfectly fine with deleting my model & creating a new one, or just reusing my model. Unfortunately, I have no idea how to find it. The console sagemaker pages are region specific:
https://us-east-2.console.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/home?region=us-east-2#/endpoints
& show no endpoints. Same with sagemaker studio. What command can I run to figure out what region I created my model in? Or to reuse my model in python rather than creating a new one each time?
I also found it odd I didn't need to specify a region in the JumpStartModel python code, and I haven't set a default region (aws configure get region returns nothing). Maybe the JumpStartModel code has a global default & I can look there?

If you used SageMaker Studio/Notebook instances, the region is automatically picked up to be the same region as the notebook. Can you try from the same environment sm_client = boto3.client('sagemaker') and sm_client.list_endpoints()? If the response is empty, then you could probably also loop through the regions and list_endpoints.

Thanks for the suggestion! Boto gave me an error "you must specify a region." I ended up manually searching through a few regions till I found them in us-west-2
